# Shindig: what is the use of RpcToken in shindig

Tags: apache-shindig

what is the use of RpcToken in shindig? I am creating Iframe manually , If I didn't set RpcToken then will it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The rpcToken is used to secure the cross-domain communication between the iframe and the parent page.  Note that this security check is skipped if the iframe is running on the same domain as the parent page.